# Generate Guid using db information

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api

I am developing ASP.NET MVC WEB API service. As everywhere i need security tokens. I have an idea to generate guid using dtabase info. For isntance i need to take entity from db, then take id, datecreated and crete guid usin this info. It will be token that will be send to client. SO he can access his data.

Problem is that i dont know how to generate it. Please advice me something to make it work.

I found interesting article http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/12/20/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp.aspx for shortening GUID.

Any help would be appreciated,
Dima.

Comment: Why not use Guid securityToken = Guid.NewGuid();

Comment: Do you want a GUID or some sort of data carrying identifier of your own devising?  It sounds like you are trying to embed information, e.g. creation date, into an identification.

Comment: @HABO Yes I want some sort of secure data carring. Is that possible to do? Youare exactly write i want to join few paramters and encode them in SHortGuid that i mentioned in my post

Comment: Why can't you use any of existing authentication/authorization mechanisms?

Comment: If the client is going to extract data from the "token" then you need to use reversible encryption.  That means the client has a decryption key.  Are you already securing the connection, i.e. using SSL?  What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you need a secure web service then why not just use WSHttpBinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just store an `AccessKey uniqueidentifier not null unique` along with every entity. You can hand that out to clients. That way you don't need to mess with encryption or hashing.

Just make sure *not* to use `Guid.NewGuid()` for this as it is not cryptographically strong. Use this:

```
public static class SecureGuidGenerator
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static RandomNumberGenerator rng;

    public static Guid GetNext()
    {
        if (rng == null) rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        var bytes = new byte[16];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        return new Guid(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't going to create a UUID - it's going to create a 128 bit long random number which is slightly different. A UUID has a formal structure. See: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt - you want a version 4 UUID (section 4 on page 13) if you want random data in the UUID.

Comment: @LarryOsterman, all of what you say is true. For security reasons I *wouldn't want* a UUID. I want random bits. This is a password. They are as unique as a UUID is, practically speaking.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but that dont is not what i want. I  want to embed id and datecreation in guid and then generate short guid. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to encode this information? Why wouldn't the approach of my answer work for you?

Comment: I'm with usr here - include a unique ID column in the db. But if you *have* to generate the GUID from the id and datecreation, RFC4122 shows how to do that - however you should note that the MD5 algorithm mentioned in the RFC is insecure.